# Not sure why I am getting the same values the constant and all the variables for a regression analysis on Python

Tags: python, statistics, regression, dummy-variable, coefficients

I am trying to run a regression analysis with dummies. I added the dummies using:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data["pizza_category"], drop_first = True)
```

Then I added the dummies into my original dataset using:

```
data[dummies.columns] = dummies
```

I then run a regression analysis using the following code:

```
Y = data["total_price"]
X = data[["Classic", "Veggie", "Supreme", "Chicken"]]
Xfull = sm.add_constant(X)
sm.OLS(Y, Xfull).fit().summary()
```

The problem arises when I run this as the outcome gives me the same coef value for the Constant and all four variables. But when I take out a variable from X (for example Chicken), it gives me a regression that actually makes sense where all the coef values are different. However, I am trying to run a regression analysis on all four variables and the output just does not make sense. Is there a way to fix this?

I tried another way of creating dummies and adding it to the data set using:

```
data["Classic"] = (data["pizza_category"] == "Classic").astype("int")
data["Veggie"] = (data["pizza_category"] == "Veggie").astype("int")
data["Supreme"] = (data["pizza_category"] == "Supreme").astype("int")
data["Chicken"] = (data["pizza_category"] == "Chicken").astype("int")
```

But when I run the regression the output remains the same with the coef for the constant and all the variables showing "-2.186e+11"

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue for regression but my data was images combined with tabular data. I got better output when I made my CNN simple by removing a few layers and removing batch normalization. I am not sure what is your network structure can you post it?

You can also try by varying learning rate, it seems like the model stuck in one of the minima.

My simple model is below, but please note that it is a CNN model. May be you can alter your model accordingly.

```
model = Sequential()
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
```